# Ruby won't install new version

Tags: ruby, installation, homebrew, ruby-build

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.7.6 but when I run
`% rbenv version`

I get:

> rbenv: version `2.7.6' is not installed (set by /Users/[USER]/Documents/[FOLDER]/.ruby-version)`

I have file *.ruby-version* containing: *2.7.6*

When running: `%. rbenv install`
It errors:

> BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)

NOTE:

- current Ruby installed is 2.6.10 installed
- running macOS v12.5 on MBP

**TERMINAL trace**

```
> (base) uxdw@MacBook-Pro [FOLDER] % rbenv install      
Downloading openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/d7939ce614029cdff0b6c20f0e2e5703158a489a72b2507b8bd51bf8c8fd10ca
Installing openssl-1.1.1q...
patching file test/v3ext.c
Installed openssl-1.1.1q to /Users/[USER]/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6

Downloading ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.6...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/sz/svbmflb15kd5dy8g9kctn9t40000gn/T/ruby-build.20220805134427.72844.lmy9oj
Results logged to /var/folders/sz/svbmflb15kd5dy8g9kctn9t40000gn/T/ruby-build.20220805134427.72844.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling date_parse.c
linking shared-object strscan.bundle
compiling date_strftime.c
compiling date_strptime.c
linking shared-object io/console.bundle
installing default date_core libraries
linking shared-object objspace.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
(base) uxdw@MacBook-Pro [FOLDER] %
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the full error message including the whole stack trace?

Comment: thanks @spickermann is the above enough or need the actual log file?

Answer (score 5):

`rbenv` is installing openssl-1.1.1q as a prereq and it will crash out due to a missing include statement, at least [one that exists in the ARM64 version](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18720). This is the case for M1 and M2 MBPs, so I'm guessing based on your description above.

1. Install openssl (I used brew, ymmv)

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

2. Add the following lines to your .zshrc for the time being

```
export PATH="`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`/lib/pkgconfig"
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`"
```

3. Close and reopen your terminal
4. Run `rbenv` again, with `CONFIGURE_OPTS` enabled

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1` rbenv install 2.7.6
```

Comment: This is an ARM specific solution intended for M-series (2020+) MacBooks. Hopefully, this solution will no longer be relevant, as the openssl team works toward a solution targeting a patch version of 1.1.1

Comment: thanks, I've gone through your steps. Openssl installs fine and added those lines to .zshrc but it's still failing on the install:
-----
% sudo CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1` rbenv install 2.7.6
Downloading openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/d7939ce614029cdff0b6c20f0e2e5703158a489a72b2507b8bd51bf8c8fd10ca
Installing openssl-1.1.1q...
patching file test/v3ext.c

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)

Comment: When I run just `brew --prefix openssl@1.1`, I can confirm it is already installed. Does your output look similar?
`~ % brew --prefix openssl@1.1 #=> /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need `sudo` to install with `rbenv`. It should install it in local directories out of your `$HOME`. I wonder if the `sudo` call is interfering