# Installing ruby but getting error "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ruby, macos, github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm building a GitHub Pages site and trying to install Ruby for my Mac as described [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/). When I run `ruby-install ruby` , I get the following:

```
linking shared-object -test-/arith_seq/extract.bundle
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_rb_arithmetic_sequence_extract", referenced from:
      _arith_seq_s_extract in extract.o
  "_rb_ary_new_capa", referenced from:
      _arith_seq_s_extract in extract.o
  "_rb_ary_store", referenced from:
      _arith_seq_s_extract in extract.o
  "_rb_define_singleton_method", referenced from:
      _Init_extract in extract.o
  "_rb_path2class", referenced from:
      _Init_extract in extract.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../../../../.ext/arm64-darwin22/-test-/arith_seq/extract.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/-test-/arith_seq/extract/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
!!! Compiling ruby 3.1.2 failed!
```

I'm totally unfamiliar with Ruby and don't know how to make any sense of this. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you using a M1 MacBook?

Comment: Seems to be an issue related to Xcode on Apple Silicon (M1/M2). I have no solution (yet). I have googled Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:  "_rb_arithmetic_sequence_extract", see https://www.rubyonmac.dev/how-to-install-ruby-on-macos-12-6-apple-silicon

Comment: I'm using Apple Silicon and ended up going with one of the options mentioned in that rubyonmac explainer and downgraded to ruby 2.7.6 (I'm using rbenv for this) and then followed these additional instructions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73251089/3050248

Comment: @PhilipAshlock but if you're using `rbenv` for managing Ruby versions (as you mentioned in the comment) why did you follow the instructions for `chruby`?

Comment: @Christian I have same issue as OP and your link worked for me. Specifically adding the enable-shared flag like so `ruby-install 3.1.2 -- --enable-shared`

Answer (score 8):

I was running into same issue as you after following the Jekyll guide.

Christian from your comments supplied [a very detailed solution](https://www.rubyonmac.dev/how-to-install-ruby-on-macos-12-6-apple-silicon) and explanation as to what's caused it.

> After updating to macOS 12.6 or 13.0, you might still be able to install 2.7.x and 3.x versions of Ruby with rbenv or asdf. With ruby-install, you’ll need to add the --enable-shared flag. Once 2.7.7 and 3.1.3 are released, you should no longer need to add any flags.

Install for me on Mac OS 12.6 worked with `ruby-install 3.1.2 -- --enable-shared`

Comment: You saved my day. Install for me on Mac OS 12.6 worked with ruby-install 3.0.4 -- --enable-shared